# Java ExecutorService and ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am experiencing a strange problem. I am trying to use Producer/Consumer Model,  Please suggest if I have done something wrong here. 
When I use the ExecutorService with fixed thread of 4, I never get any exception and program runs BUT when I use ThreadPoolExecutor , it gives me the exception.  Can't find out what is the error! Please advise!

code of ExecutorService:

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<BillableList> list =new ArrayBlockingQueue<BillableList>(2);
ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4, threadFactory);

  threadPool.execute(new BillingConsu(network,"consumer->"+Thread.currentThread(), list)); 
  threadPool.execute(new BillingConsu(network,"consumer->"+Thread.currentThread(), list));
  threadPool.execute(new BillingConsu(network,"consumer->"+Thread.currentThread(), list));

Future producerStatus = threadPool.submit(new BillProdu(this.network,"Producer", list)); 
producerStatus.get();
threadPool.shutdown(); 

 while (!threadPool.isTerminated()) {
 threadPool.shutdown();
 threadPool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
```

Code of ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<BillableList> list =new ArrayBlockingQueue<BillableList>(4);
BlockingQueue<Runnable> worksQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100);
RejectedExecutionHandler executionHandler = new MyRejectedExecutionHandelerImpl();
ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5,5, 10, 
 TimeUnit.SECONDS, worksQueue,threadFactory, executionHandler);
 Future producerStatus = threadPool.submit(new BillProdu(this.network,"Producer", list)); 
 producerStatus.get(); 

  threadPool.execute(new BillingConsu(network,"consumer 1", list)); 
  threadPool.execute(new BillingConsu(network,"consumer 2", list));
  threadPool.execute(new BillingConsu(network,"consumer 3", list));
  threadPool.execute(new BillingConsu(network,"consumer 4", list));
  threadPool.shutdown(); 

             while (!threadPool.isTerminated()) {
              threadPool.shutdown();
                threadPool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           }
```

Exception when I run ThreadPoolExecutor :

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.axis.utils.Messages.<clinit>(Messages.java:36)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder$1.run    (EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:141)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory    (EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:113)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory    (EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getEngineConfiguration(Service.java:813)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
    at org.tempuri.OnlineBillingLocator.<init>(OnlineBillingLocator.java:28)
    at com.mixem.sdc.sms.StsSmsConnection.<init>(StsSmsConnection.java:40)
    at BillingConsu.doStsBilling(BillingConsu.java:202)
    at BillingConsu.run(BillingConsu.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:172)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at LogFileWriter.append(LogFileWriter.java:45)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders    (AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.debug(Log4JLogger.java:177)
    at org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle.getBundle(ProjectResourceBundle.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis.i18n.MessagesConstants.<clinit>(MessagesConstants.java:32)
```

Log4J properties File

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, fileout
log4j.appender.fileout = LogFileWriter
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.File = /logs/billinglogs.log
```

LogFileWriter  Append Code

```
@Override
public void append(LoggingEvent event) {
try {
setFile(appendLevelToFileName((String) MDC.get(ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME),
event.getLevel().toString()), fileAppend, bufferedIO,bufferSize);
} catch (IOException ie) {
errorHandler.error("Error occured while setting file for the log level "+ event.getLevel(), ie,
ErrorCode.FILE_OPEN_FAILURE);
    }
super.append(event);
}
```

MDC put code inside LogFileWriter

```
@Override
public void activateOptions() {
MDC.put(ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME, fileName);
super.activateOptions();
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to log to null file. What line is 202 in BillingConsu.java?

Comment: Like @whoAmI says. This seems to be a log4j configuration problem, not a thread pool related problem...

Comment: @whoAmI  It is    resp = new StsSmsConnection().doRequest(sms);         But it is the same file that is run by ExecutorService!! and no exception

Comment: @fge But in ExecutorService  no log4j problem.. the program runs..

Comment: In any event, you should add the log4j configuration to the post, maybe this will show the problem

Comment: @fge Added log4j Configuration file

Comment: Can you post the code for `LogFileWriter.append`?

Comment: @JohnVint  Added that method code! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I expected you are failing because of thread-locality.  The line here is almost certainly returning null

```
MDC.get(ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME)
```

When/where do you `MDC.put`?  The issue here is that MDC uses a thread-local map.  So when you are running the Callable it will attempt to log in a separate thread.  That thread has not been registered with MDC and `get` will return null.

Imagine your application looks similar to

```
Main-Thread
  MDC.put -> sets thread-local-map(Main-Thread, ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME)

Executor-Thread-1
Executor-Thread-2
Executor-Thread-N
```

Now when you are in Executor-Thread-1..N it will do

```
Executor-Thread-N
    MDC.get(Executor-Thread-N, ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME)
```

It will return null

If you run outside of the Executor Service threads it works

```
Main-Thread
   MDC.get(Main-Thread, ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME) // will be non-null
```

So your next question is,  "Why is it not failing with an ExecutorService?"  It probably is  or would be and may not be reported.  I do notice your order of submission to the ExecutorService is different then TPE.  May want to try and match them up and see if you get the same output.

Edit:  May want to try this as a fix

```
ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
        return Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                MDC.put(ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME, fileName);
                r.run();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This happened when I commented out all the Log message output code!!

Comment: I have added the code for MDC.put code that is in LogFileWriter

Comment: See if you can invoke `MDC.put(ORIG_LOG_FILE_NAME, fileName);` from the `BillingConsu.call` method prior to `doStsBilling`.  Probably not the fix you want.  I will post maybe a better solution if that works.

Comment: I removed all the code that refers to log4j from all the classes.. and now it's working.. So this proves.. it's something to do with log4j .  I will try your way and come back.. I think you are at target  MDC.get and put part!

Comment: @MadanMadan Updated with something you can try to use to resolve this problem without having to put it in the Callable.

Comment: Thanks mate! you saved my days!!! LogWriter was the culprit here!! Thanks billion times.. !!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30781/discussion-between-john-vint-and-madan-madan)